# CSS3 Rotation issue

Tags: html, css, rotation

I'm setting everything in a div tag to appear horizontal. However i have elements in this div tag that i want to appear vertical.

My horizontal styled div is

```
    /* Safari */
-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);

/* Firefox */
-moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);

/* IE */
-ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);

/* Opera */
-o-transform: rotate(-90deg);

/* Internet Explorer */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
```

How would i effectively get rid of this transformation on a seperate div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to reset it on the child element, undo the rotation ( http://jsfiddle.net/yDGqz/):

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
-o-transform: rotate(90deg);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=1);
```

You might want to set the [`transform-origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/transform-origin) property to change the rotation origin of the element.

Comment: PS. [documentation on the Microsoft's rotation filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532918(v=vs.85).aspx).